# Prestashop "Order cannot be saved" on checkout?

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, checkout

Does anyone know why this is happening? It seems really random when it occurs, and there's nothing in the apache log being reported.

My customers are reporting that they're using the prestashop checkout module, and when they pay for an order the checkout page displays the error: "Order cannot be saved". I've looked at where that appears in the code and it says that it's trying to do something with paypal.

Anyone have any ideas please.

Thanks

Comment: just guessing, but have to connected the prestashop to your paypal account? Is there somewhere you supposed to put a paypal API key?

Comment: Hello, paypal works most of the time and is setup correctly.

Comment: Take a look to log files at `var/logs` inside your PrestaShop dir, and to Advanced configuration > Logs at backend.